# mysql php query CASE selecting columns in second table based on columns in first table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

table1 - table that defines what sensors are present

```
serialN  |  sensor1  |  sensor2  | 
122      |    1      |    1      |
123      |    1      |    0      |
```

table 2 - table with actual sensor data.

```
serialN  |  sensor1  |  sensor2  | 
123      |    23     |    -0.0F  |
123      |    22     |    -0.0F  |
122      |    19     |    -0.0F  |
123      |    33     |    -0.0F  |
122      |    26     |    -0.0F  |
123      |    24     |    -0.0F  |
```

How can I do a PHP mysql Query to get results where only those columns in table 2 are selected ONLY if their corresponding table1 counter part is 1 For a given serialN

So my results if I want data for serialN=123 should be

```
serialN  |  sensor1  |
123      |    23     |
123      |    22     |
123      |    33     |
123      |    24     |
```

Comment: Can sensor2 be null when sensor2 in table 1 is 0? or you want a dynamic number of columns? Or they can't both be 1 at the same time?

Comment: @FilipeSilva sensor2 is not NULL. there can be case where both sensor1 and sensor2 can be 1 on table1

Comment: what i was asking with the null reference was if you could use a query that returns always two columns, but whenever sensor2 in table 1 is 0, you would get null in the resulting query for sensor2.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql's case statement has your back (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).  PHP trickery is unnecessary:

```
select 
case when t1.sensor1=1 then t2.sensor1 when t1.sensor2=1 then t2.sensor2 end
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.serialN = t2.serialN
```

Comment: It brings null on sensor2 if sensor2 on table1 is 0. Is there a way to just select columns only if table1 value=1?

Answer (score 0):

See if this fits your needs:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.sensor1 = 1 THEN t2.sensor1 ELSE null END AS 'SENSOR1',
       CASE WHEN t1.sensor2 = 1 THEN t2.sensor2 ELSE null END AS 'SENSOR2'
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 T1 ON t1.serialN = t2.serialN
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a1c4/1)</kbd>

Comment: thanks but it seems to be returning NULLS on sensor 2. Can you see my updated question? may be I did not phrase it right.

Comment: @aVC. This query always returns two columns, but whenever table1 value is 0 it returns null, otherwise returns table2 value. If you want only one column you might have to do something with prepared statements in your php code, but there i can't help you, sorry.